# Rails custom attribute validation not allowing creation of new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have an answer model which belongs to a question which has a "correct" boolean column. Ideally a question can have only 1 correct answer ( much like the stackoverflow system).

I have the following controller + model code which uses a `toggle_correct` method to toggle the "correct" boolean value in the view (all of which works nicely).

When i try and create a new answer the `one_correct_answer` validation error is raised even though the correct column is set to default: false in the migration and the value is set to 0 (false) in the application POST trace

How can I amend my code so that a this validation only allows there to be 1 correct answer per question and doesn't interrupt the creation of a new an answer object?

answer.rb

```
validate :one_correct_answer

  def one_correct_answer
    answers = self.question.answers.map(&:correct)
    errors.add(:user_id, "You can't have more than 1 correct answer #{answers}") if answers & [true]
    logger.debug("Answers array #{answers}")
  end

def toggle_correct(attribute)
    toggle(attribute).update_attributes({attribute => self[attribute]})
  end
```

answers_controller.rb

```
def correct 
    @answer = Answer.find(params[:id])
    if @answer.toggle_correct(:correct)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: "Answer submitted" }
      format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

_answer.html.erb

```
<div id="correct_answer_<%= answer.id %>" class="<%= answer.correct == true ? 'green-tick' : 'default-tick' %>">
    <% if answer.question.user == current_user %>
        <%= link_to "✓", correct_answer_path(answer), id: "tick", class: "correct_#{answer.id}", remote: true, method: :put %>
    <% else %>
        <% if answer.correct == true %>
           <div id="tick", class='correct_<% answer.id %>'> ✓</div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it will fail is that you are adding an error if any answer associated to the question is correct. And you test this even though the answer you are trying to save is correct or not. So the first thing you should do is to only check if there are any correct answers if the answer you are trying to save is indeed correct, like this:

```
validate :one_correct_answer, if: :correct?
```

This way, the method one_correct_answer will only be validated if the current answer is correct.

However, you still have one additional problem. If the answer you are trying to save is correct, then the method will be called and it will add an error if there is any answer that is correct... which it will probably be since the current answer should also be listed in that association. So what you want to do is to check if there is an additional answer that is correct.

So in the end, I would probably end up validating it like this instead:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :correct, scope: :question_id, if: :correct?
```

What this will do is that it validates the unique combination of the question_id column and the correct column, but only if correct is true. That makes it so that you can have multiple false but only one true correct column per question.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably here:

```
errors.add(:user_id, "You can't have more than 1 correct answer #{answers}") if answers & [true]
```

`answers & [true]` will always return an array(since `answers` is an array), and blank arrays are true values in Ruby.

Even if they were false values, your condition wouldn't work, since there has to be one correct answer, and your condition would check that there are none.

I would use this condition:

```
self.question.answers.count(&:correct) <= 1
```